# Format a number to a maximum width and variable precision

Tags: string, python-3.x, numbers, number-formatting

I would like to format a number (integer or float) to a string with the following requirements:

1. The total width must be `n`
2. The precision should be variable but minimal (between 0 and `p`)
3. Uses leading space if necessary

With `n`, a parameter given by the developer (me), and `p` the number of decimal excluding trailing zeros.

For example, with `n = 8`:

- `12.345     -> "  12.345"`
- `12345.67   -> "12345.67"`
- `123456.78  -> "123456.8"`
- `1234567.89 -> " 1234568"`
- `12.3456789 -> "12.34568"`
- `0.33333333 -> "0.333333"`

So far, I have this which is almost working:

```
def fmt(x, n):
    ffw = "{:.{}f}".format(x, n)
    cln = ffw[:n].rstrip("0").rstrip(".")

    return "{:>{}s}".format(cln, n)
```

It does work (except it does not round numbers correctly), but it looks very complicated, and I feel like there is an easier way. Do I miss something somewhere?